# Whats wrong with my nested subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

So I'm solving the interactive tutorial [http://www.sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_Nobel_Tutorial](http://www.sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT%5ffrom%5fNobel%5fTutorial)
However the bonus part doesn't have a solution.

**Here's the question:**
In which years was the Physics prize awarded but no Chemistry prize.

```
SELECT yr FROM nobel
WHERE subject = 'Physics' AND yr NOT IN
(SELECT yr FROM nobel WHERE subject = 'Literature')
```

I got the output

```
1943
1935
1918
1914
```

When the tutorial said the answer is

```
1933
1924
1919
1917
```

I don't understand why my solution is wrong

EDIT: I saw the careless mistake that 'Literature' should be 'Chemistry' but it still seems to be invalid

Comment: Perhaps you should change `'Literature'` to `'Chemistry'`.

Comment: omg, how do i close this question

Comment: @CodeCrusader Replacing `Literature` with `Chemistry` is not enough to get the correct result, though - there's one more problem which shows up in years when the award in physics is given to multiple winners.

Comment: Incidentally, does the question require you to solve this with a nested query?

Comment: @Strawberry its the only way i could think of, i havent gone to the advanced tutorial yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your query:

- You mistyped `Chemistry` (your query says `Literature` instead)
- You did not ask for `distinct` results

Here is your modified query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT yr
FROM nobel
WHERE subject = 'Physics' AND yr NOT IN
(SELECT yr FROM nobel WHERE subject = 'Chemistry')
```

`DISTINCT` is important, because in 1933 the physics prize has been awarded to multiple winners - namely, Dirac and Schrödinger. These two rows from the table result in two entries for 1933 in the output, which you do not want.

Answer (score 1):

> In which years was the Physics prize awarded but no Chemistry prize.

:) Read Your task again...

> WHERE subject = 'Physics' AND yr NOT IN
>   (SELECT yr FROM nobel WHERE subject = 'Literature')

Answer (score 1):

I want to note that that "Warning" on the question is not correct.  You can do this with a `group by` and `having` clause:

```
select n.yr
from nobel n
group by n.yr
having sum(n.subject = 'Physics' ) > 0 and
       sum(n.subject = 'Chemistry' ) = 0;
```

I am guessing that at this point, the tutorial hasn't introduced `group by`, `having`, or using booleans results as integers.  However, you do not need a `join` or subquery to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.yr 
  FROM nobel x
  LEFT
  JOIN nobel y 
    ON y.yr = x.yr
   AND y.subject = 'chemistry'
 WHERE x.subject = 'physics'
   AND y.yr IS NULL;
```